# VBA: User Form and Macro Called in the User Form give a Different Result

Tags: vba, format, vlookup

I have USER FORM with several different Macro attached.

When I launch the macro from the user form I have a result, when I lunch the macro from the Module, I have a different one.

Below the code of the macro:

```
Sub WeekEndsCheck()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Ret As Variant

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Range("B2"), Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    On Error Resume Next
    Ret = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, _
          Worksheets("DataBase").Range("A:A"), 1, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Ret <> "" Then
        If cell = Ret Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
        Ret = ""
    End If
    Next

For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    On Error Resume Next
    Ret = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, _
          Worksheets("DataBase").Range("A:A"), 1, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Ret <> "" Then
        If cell = Ret Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
        Ret = ""
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I am trying to check through a `VLOOK UP` if in a range of dates are contained some dates from another sheet called database.

I am basically checking that my dates are not weekends.

I don't want to check just for weekends but also for working days by currency. That's why I have created the database that will repplicate the same code.

Comment: What does it mean to "check ... for working days by currency"?

Comment: Remove both instances of `On Error Resume Next` and try it again. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: If i remove it it gives me error 1004. Run-time error 1004

Answer (score 0):

This is more robust, and no need for error handling if you drop WorksheetFunction:

```
Sub WeekEndsCheck()

    Dim cell As Range, ws As Worksheet, rngData As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngData = Worksheets("DataBase").Range("A:A")

    'qualify all range() calls with a worksheet
    For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("B2"), ws.Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Cells
        'use Match() and drop the WorksheetFunction
        'Edit: when matching dates need to use CLng() to convert search date to a number
        If IsError(Application.Match(CLng(cell.Value), rngData, 0)) Then cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next cell

    For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Range("D2"), ws.Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Cells
        If IsError(Application.Match(CLng(cell.Value), rngData, 0)) Then cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Is still not working, the code you gave me paint all the cells, of the two columns. Which is not the result of the v look up. There must be a problem on the buttons, because when i launch it from the developer is working perfectly. Is there a way to implement the Vlook up with dates formats, maybe the problem is in matching dates.

Comment: Are your dates on both sheets actual dates (and not for example text that looks like dates)?

Comment: Hello, they are actual dates dd/mm/aaaa

Comment: Sorry - forgot about the whole date issue.  See my update above.